# Rolling 12 months with increase in penalty percentage in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, percentage

I got this report requirement which is way ahead of me to come up with a solution. Please check the below scenarios and provide me with logic how to proceed with this in SSRS.

Scenario 1 – cure period for first non-comp

•   A one time 3-month cure period applies to the first instance of non-com, during a rolling 12 month period.
•   If still out of Com in the third month of the cure period penalty will begin accruing. In the scenario below, the first penalty is based on the performance in month 4. A 3% rebate is received based on the total value of the month 4 invoice.

Scenario 2 – cure period for any subsequent non compliance

•   Any subsequent non-com of any KPI, during a 12 month period, will be given a 1-month cure period
•   Further,  penalty increases 1% per month of non-com
•   In the scenario below, a 1-month cure period is given for CHAT in month 3. Also a 1-month cure period is given for SA in month 8 and month 11. A rebate of 6% would be due in month 4 and that would increase for month 5,6,9 and 10.

Scenario 3  - relationship between metrics

•   Where two or more metrics are non-com, during a 12 month period, the then current penalty % will apply to other metrics, as outlined below
•   At the end of the rolling 12 month period then all penalties are reset. Note a rolling month is not necessarily tied to a calendar year or contract year.

Scenario 4  - relationship between metrics, exception

•   The one exception to the scenario above is when performance goes from Level 1 to Level 2 non-compliance. The penalty % could go up by more than 1% point from the previous non-com month.

Please refer the link for Diagrams of the above:
[image]

Any logic that this can be resolved or is it even possible to achieve in SSRS if not why? and if yes How can be achieved? Any help is very much appreciated

code:

```
select survey date, survey id, overall experience from survey 
where survey date between startdate(6/1/2013) and enddate(5/31/2014).
```

Condition is if overall exp >=4.5 then Target  and  if overall exp <4.5 and >4.25 then Level1 and if overall exp <=4.25 then level2

Thank You

Comment: Yes, you have laid out a very specific question that looks like it came straight from a requirement document. To answer your question, yes, you can do this in ssrs. What does your database look like?

Comment: Hi lrb could you please give me some idea on how this can be achived. Please see mt edited section above for the sql code and condition